# Open URL with webView once application deploys

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm playing around with some code that should open a URL within a webView as the Mac Application loads. My problem is, that I'm not sure how to declare the `WebView *myWebView;` within the openAd.h file.

**openAd.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import  <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface openAd : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>;

WebView *myWebView;

@end
```

**openAd.m**

```
#import "openAd.h"

@implementation openAd : NSObject ;

- (void)windowDidLoad

{

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:requestObj];


}
@end
```

... not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in .m

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
  NSString *strURL = @"http://www.google.com/";
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strURL];
  NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

  myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
  myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
  [self.view addSubview:myWeb];

  [myWeb loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: Note that the main thing you're missing here is `myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];` - declaring an instance variable doesn't initialize it.  Also, you should put `WebView *myWebView;` inside `{}` unless you meant to declare a global variable.

Comment: @AAron If you read carefully, in .h file myWebView is declared as global variable already

Comment: I know, I'm saying the author probably didn't want to do that.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I was addressing @Pxlc, not you :-)

Comment: He's developing an osx application. On osx there is not the UIWebView class. For the love of god, read the question.